# PostgreSQL: Aggregate into array and join

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

Kind of new to pgsql, what i'm looking for is a bit of common need, I think, but I still wasn't able to find a solution.

I have 3 tables:
**users**

```
user_id|username|password
-------|--------|--------
   1   | guest  | blabla
   2   | admin  | blabla
```

**roles**

```
role_id|name | descr
-------|-----|--------
   1   |role1|role one
   2   |role2|role two
```

**user_roles**

```
user_id|role_id
-------|-------
   2   |   1
   2   |   2
```

I want to display a table of user along with all its' roles, my guess (feel free to correct me), the way to do that would be:

1. Group user roles into array:
   `select user_id,array_agg(role_id) from user_roles group by user_id where user_id = 2;`
2. Somehow join the array of `array_agg(role_id)` into `roles` to select the role names.

As you can see, I'm a bit confused on how to do #2. Is this the best way to do what I want? Is there something wrong with how I've build my db tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your query, you would first do the join between the tables and at last aggregate on the `name` column.
Note that it may be prettier [using](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) `string_agg(r.name,',')`

```
select ur.user_id,array_agg(r.name) 
from user_roles ur, 
     roles r
where ur.role_id = r.role_id
 and ur.user_id = 2
group by ur.user_id;
```